# How to select the value of the label for a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck on this one. I'd like to grab the ***value of the label*** for a field to use it in an alert as part of a validation script. Here is my code:

(The function is being called on the `onblur` event (`isFieldBlank(this)`).

```
function isFieldBlank(that) {
    if($(that).val()=="") {
      var fieldLabel = $('label[for*="' + that + '"]).val();
      alert(fieldLabel);
      alert("You must provide a value for: ") + fieldLabel;
      $(that).addClass("error");
      $(that).focus();
      return false;
    } else {
        $(that).removeClass("error");       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
var fieldLabel = $('label[for*="' + $(that).attr('id') + '"]').text();
```

Comment: Awesome. Got it to work. Thanks lucuma, thecodeparadox and Engineer. Will accept answer in 3 minutes. Final code:  `function isFieldBlank(that) {
 if($(that).val()=="") {
  var fieldLabel = $('label[for*="' + $(that).attr('id') + '"]').text();
  alert("You must provide a value for: " + fieldLabel);
  $(that).addClass("error");
  $(that).focus();
  return false;
 } else {
  $(that).removeClass("error");  
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
var fieldLabel = $('label[for*="' + that + '"]).val();
```

should be

```
var fieldLabel = $('label[for*="' + that.id + '"]').text(); // here, .text() 
                                                           // not .val()
                                               //^--> missed a quote here
```

`.val()` is used for retrieve input value.  You need to use `.text()` here.

and also you need to convert `that` to `that.id` to get the `id`.

Read more about

- **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text)**
- **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val)**

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use something like `that.id` or `$(that).attr('id')` ?